# fix a local resource path with webpack encore

Tags: symfony, webpack

I'm using webpack encore with symfony 5 and i'm trying to add datatables to my project :

```
    .addEntry('pdfmake', './assets/scripts/pdfmake.min.js')
    .addEntry('vfs-fonts', './assets/scripts/vfs_fonts.js')
    .addEntry('datatables-min', './assets/scripts/datatables.min.js')
    .addEntry('datatables-buttons', './assets/scripts/datatables.buttons.min.js')
    .addEntry('buttons-html5', './assets/scripts/buttons.html5.min.js')
    .addEntry('buttons-print', './assets/scripts/buttons.print.min.js')
    .addEntry('buttons-bootstrap', './assets/scripts/buttons.bootstrap.min.js')
    .addEntry('datatables-bootstrap4', './assets/scripts/datatables.bootstrap4.min.js')
    .addEntry('datatable-script', './assets/scripts/datatable.js')
```

I called libraries inside the webpack config file and inside my twig

The data tables work fine but in my main js file i have an i18next config function :

```
 // init i18n and load language file
  i18next.use(XHR).init({
      debug: false,
      fallbackLng: "en",
      backend: {
        loadPath: "build/{{lng}}.json"
      },
      returnObjects: true
    },
    function (err, t) {
      // resources have been loaded
      jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
    }
  );
```

the local path inside the config is build/en.json for the english language but i'm using the datatable in `http://localhost/admin/user/` so i'm getting this error in my console :

> /admin/user/build/en.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a relative path.
You should be using an absolute path.
Just add a preceding forward slash `"/"`:

```
 loadPath: "/build/{{lng}}.json"
```

https://medium.com/@colinlmcdonald/absolute-vs-relative-paths-7ffd8e31d49c